# What is the expression to hide a column in an SSRS report if the current month number > an integer?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to hide a column on my ssrs report based on a condition that the current month aka month(today()) is a specific integer.

For example, I have to hide "column11" until November 1st and "column12" until December 1st.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have in mind hiding some columns could result in duplicate values into your report, especially if those columns are the ones making unique your rows.

Now for your specific case you can use:

```
=IIf(
(Month(Today()) >= 2 AND Day(Today()) >=5)
AND
(Month(Today()) <= 3 AND Day(Today()) <=4)
,true,false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In ssrs when you right click column you will find column visibility option.
There you can write expression for hiding I.e if true it will hide column, if false then will
Show column.

Expression will be something like below.

```
IIF(Month(today())<11,true,false)
```

And for December it will be

IIF(Month(today())<12,true,false)

Note: this is pseudo code and may have typo error

Comment: Thank you for this. How would I write this if I were to make a column visible only between Feb 5th and March 4th of any year?